# CircleCI: how to share variables between parallel jobs?

Tags: circleci

**Context**

I’m running 3 E2E tests as parallel and my goal is to send notification to Slack when one of test is failed. I tried two approaches.

1. After e2e is finished, send notification → but, it’s impossible because job cannot be executed when required job(e2e test job) is failed.
2. When one of parallel tests is failed, send notification → duplicated notifications are sent,

So each test should know whether one of tests already sent notification through environment variable.
To implement second method, **I should be able to share environment variable between parallel tests(jobs).** But, I couldn’t any clues in docs/discussion/support of CircleCI. How can I do? And, if this is impossible how can I do this in hacky way?

**Example**

Parallel Tests: A, B, C.

When A is finished eariler than B and C, A set environment variable `isTestFailed` as true dynamically and sent Slack notification message. After sending, B and C were finished and checked `isTestFailed` is true. They didn’t send notification because `isTestFailed` is true and finish the test. Therefore, only one notification message is exist in slack.

**Diagram**

```
build ------> e2e test A ------> Send notification to Slack and set boolean flag
      ------> e2e test B ------> Check boolean flag is true, don't send
      ------> e2e test C ------> Check boolean flag is true, don't send
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need a shared variable.

Couldn't you postpone the notification in a dedicated step which will be triggered **on fail** only?

You run your tests without sending notification, then you add a step like this:

```yaml
    - run:
        name: 'send notification if one or more test failed'
        background: false
        when: on_fail
        command: |
          # Do stuff
```

Hope this could help!